# Get LocalDateTime from a DateTimeObject

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime

I'm having problems with getting the local time using Joda Time library. Here's a simple example of what I'm trying to do.

```
package simple;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class TestJodaLocalTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //time in UTC standard
        DateTime processingDate = DateTime.now();
        //local time
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = processingDate.
                withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault()).toLocalDateTime();

        DateTimeFormatter fmtDate = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        DateTimeFormatter fmtHour = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss");

        System.out.println("Date: " + fmtDate.print(processingDate));
        System.out.println("Time: " + fmtHour.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).
                print(processingDate));
        System.out.println("Local date: " + fmtDate.print(localDateTime));
        System.out.println("Local time: " + fmtHour.print(localDateTime));

    }

}
```

I was expecting that, when printing the local time, I would get the time on the timezone from where my application is running, but I got an identical time to the UTC DateTime.

```
Date: 06/12/2012
Time: 12:55:49
Local date: 06/12/2012
Local time: 12:55:49
```

What did I missed here?

Answer (score 1):

This comment may be part of the problem:

```
//time in UTC standard
DateTime processingDate = DateTime.now();
```

No, `DateTime.now()` returns the current time in the default time zone. So when you later use `withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault())` that's a no-op.

However, I'd still have expected `fmtHour.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).print(processingDate)` to convert to UTC.

Indeed, that's what I get when I manually set the default time zone to something other than UTC:

```
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeZone pacific = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles");
        DateTimeZone.setDefault(pacific);

        DateTime processingDate = DateTime.now();
        //local time
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = processingDate.
            withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault()).toLocalDateTime();

        DateTimeFormatter fmtDate = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        DateTimeFormatter fmtHour = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss");

        System.out.println("Date: " + fmtDate.print(processingDate));
        System.out.println("Time: " + fmtHour.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).
                           print(processingDate));
        System.out.println("Local date: " + fmtDate.print(localDateTime));
        System.out.println("Local time: " + fmtHour.print(localDateTime));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Date: 06/12/2012
Time: 13:19:35
Local date: 06/12/2012
Local time: 05:19:35
```

Are you sure the problem isn't just that your default time zone *is* UTC?

Comment: Well, that's indeed the problem, I tried to get my default timezone and it was UTC. On the other hand, my computer clock is set to UTC-3 with daylight saving time. How is that possible? (usign windows xp, if that matters)

Comment: @ThiagoMoraes: Perhaps some of your other code is setting the default time zone to UTC? It's hard to say without knowing more. I suggest you try a simple console application which *just* prints out the default time zone. If that shows your "real" time zone, then you must be fudging in your other code somewhere.

Comment: I've done this test by just inserting "DateTimeZone d = DateTimeZone.getDefault();" on the beginning of your solution and then entering in debug. I'll search a little and come back if I find anything useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following (I'm in GMT+2:00 time zone):

```
public class TestJodaLocalTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTime utcNow = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC);
        DateTime localNow = utcNow.withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault());

        DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateHourMinuteSecond();

        System.out.println("UTC   now: " + fmt.print(utcNow));
        System.out.println("Local now: " + fmt.print(localNow));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
UTC   now: 2012-12-07T17:43:43
Local now: 2012-12-07T19:43:43
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that for many situations the DateTime class may be better than LocalDateTime for implementing "local" date/time. It all depends on what you mean by "local" - local to this PC or device and based on its current timezone, or completely independent of all timezones.